# Why Geojson dumps 0 kB file in Python?

Tags: python, json, geojson, folium

I am trying to generate a geojson file in Python. Below is my code.
Code was ran with no error but generate a 0 kb geojson file.How can I fix my code? I want only geo coordinates and land no in my file.

```
from geojson import GeoJSONEncoder, Feature, Point, Polygon, 
FeatureCollection, GeometryCollection

chopsize = 1
n=0
x0=0
y0=0
for y0 in range(0, 16, chopsize): #y
   for x0 in range(0, 2, chopsize): #x
      box = (x0, y0,
         x0+chopsize, y0,
         x0+chopsize,
         y0+chopsize,
         x0, y0+chopsize,
         x0,y0)
      n=n+1
      landno=''
      landno += f'Land No: {n}'
      coordinates = []
      coordinates +=  [[x0, y0],[x0 + 
      chopsize, y0], 
      [x0+chopsize,y0+chopsize], 
      [x0,y0+chopsize],[x0,y0]]

properties=[landno]
poly=Polygon(coordinates)
geo_collection = GeometryCollection(poly)
my_feature=(Feature(properties))

geo_data=[geo_collection,my_feature]
feature_collection = FeatureCollection(geo_data)
print(feature_collection)

with open('myfile.geojson', 'w') as f:
      geojson.dumps(geo_data, sort_keys=True)
f.close()
```

Comment: There are problems with your indentation making it unclear what your intended program flow is

Comment: Thank you for information. It was a mistkae during copying the code. I tried to correct it

Comment: Your edited code will cause a NameError exception when *geojson.dumps(geo_data, sort_keys=True)* is attempted. However, that will happen **after** your output file has been created resulting in an empty file. There is no attempt to write any data to the file

Comment: Thank you. I modified the line before "f.close" as "f.write(geojson.dumps(my_feature, sort_keys=True))". It worked